# How to address the need to access to specific implementations in a scenario involving polymorphism?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, abstraction, visitor-pattern

I stumbled on this problem that I am not able to solve properly. Here is some explanation.

**Code**

I have these Product classes:

```
public abstract class Product
{
    public int BaseParam {get;set;}
}

public class SpecificProductA : Product
{
    public int ParamA {get;set;}
}

public class SpecificProductB : Product
{
    public int ParamB {get;set;}
}
```

And I have these Consumer classes:

```
public interface IConsumer
{
    void Consume(Product product);
}

public class ConcreteConsumerA : IConsumer
{
    public void Consume(Product product)
    {
        /* I need ParamA of SpecificProductA */
    }
}

public class ConcreteConsumerB : IConsumer
{
    public void Consume(Product product)
    {
        /* I need ParamB of SpecificProductB */
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I need the concrete implementations of the IConsumer interface to access specific parts of the Product. ConcreteConsumerA will only be able to consume ProductA and ConcreteConsumerB can only consume ProductB. This breaks the nice abstraction that I had with Consumer & Product.

**Solution 1: Casting**

The first and obvious thing that can be done is **casting** the product instance to the specific product. It works but it is not ideal as I rely on the runtime to throw any errors if anything is wrong with the type.

**Solution 2: Breaking the inheritance of the product classes**

The other solution has been to **break the Product inheritance** to something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int BaseParam {get;set;}

    public SpecificProductA ProductA {get;set;}

    public SpecificProductB ProductB {get;set;}
}

public class SpecificProductA
{
    public int ParamA {get;set;}
}

public class SpecificProductB
{
    public int ParamB {get;set;}
}
```

**Solution 3: Generics**

I can also make the IConsumer interface **generic** like this:

```
    public interface IConsumer<TProduct> where TProduct: Product
    {
        void Consume(Product product);
    }

    public class ConcreteConsumerA : IConsumer<SpecificProductA>
    {
        public void Consume(SpecificProductA productA)
        {
            /* I now have access to ParamA of SpecificProductA */
        }
    }

    public class ConcreteConsumerB : IConsumer<SpecificProductB>
    {
        public void Consume(SpecificProductB productB)
        {
            /* I now have access to ParamA of SpecificProductB */
        }
    }
```

However, like cancer, this generic interface is now spreading into the whole program which is not ideal either.

I am not certain what is wrong here and which rule has been broken. Maybe it is a design issue that needs to be changed. Is there a better solution that the ones provided to solve this problem?

Comment: Could the params also be stored in a public `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, int>` where the `Key` is the current name of the property? That way the existing properties can read from the `ReadOnlyDictionary`, but also **all** properties can be read, even from the base class, through the `ReadOnlyDictionary`.

Comment: @mjwills That's just a different way of removing all static typing from the solution, just like if you cast everything.

Comment: Correct @Servy. Software is about tradeoffs. I am not saying this is a _great_ tradeoff (since I don't know enough about the finer details of the context) - but it is an option. _Feel free to post another option if you have one._

Comment: Generic IConsumer is solution here. If you want to avoid spreading the only right way is to cast

Comment: @mjwills In the context of a configuration situation, it could definitely be done. However, in other scenarios where it is another kind of object, let's say a Product, it would feel weird...

Comment: I agree @Kzrystof. given your base class was called `Configuration` that seemed reasonable to assume that was your problem space. Is it really Products instead? Or are you looking for a solution that handles both?

Comment: @mjwills As a matter of fact, I ended with that problem twice. One with a Configuration context but the other is similar to a Product. So I am looking for a solution to both issues. I will adjust the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that solves my problem: the Visitor Pattern. The trick was to find another abstraction (called here `ICommonInterface`) between my `IConsumer` and my `Product` and let the visitors deals with the details.

```
public interface IProductVisitor
{
      ICommonInterface Visit(SpecificProductA productA);

      ICommonInterface Visit(SpecificProductB productB);
}

/* The purpose of this abstract class is to minimize the impact of the changes if I had to support another SpecificProductC. */ 
public abstract class ProductVisitor : IProductVisitor
{
      public virtual ICommonInterface GetCommonInterface(SpecificProductA productA)
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public virtual ICommonInterface GetCommonInterface(SpecificProductB productB)
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
}

public sealed class SpecificProductAVisitor : ProductVisitor
{
      public override ICommonInterface GetCommonInterface(SpecificProductA productA)
      {
          /* This guy will deal with ParamA of SpecificProductA */
          return new ImplACommonInterface(productA);
      }
}

public sealed class SpecificProductBVisitor : ProductVisitor
{
      public override ICommonInterface GetCommonInterface(SpecificProductB productB)
      {
          /* This guy will deal with ParamB of SpecificProductB */
          return new ImplBCommonInterface(productB);
      }
}
```

Then I have to allow the new `IProductVisitor` on the `Product` classes:

```
public abstract class Product
{
    public int BaseParam { get; set; }

    public abstract ICommonInterface Visit(IProductVisitor productVisitor);
}

public class SpecificProductA : Product
{
    public int ParamA {get;set;}

    public override ICommonInterface Visit(IProductVisitor productVisitor)
    {
        /* Forwards the SpecificProductA to the Visitor */
        return productVisitor.GetCommonInterface(this);
    }
}

public class SpecificProductB : Product
{
    public int ParamB {get;set;}

    public override ICommonInterface Visit(IProductVisitor productVisitor)
    {
        /* Forwards the SpecificProductB to the Visitor */
        return productVisitor.GetCommonInterface(this);
    }
}
```

Each `IConsumer` implementations can now do the following without having the need to cast anything:

```
    public interface IConsumer
    {
        void Consume(Product product);

        ICommonObject Visit(IProductVisitor productVisitor);
    }

    public class ConcreteConsumerA : IConsumer
    {
        public void Consume(Product product)
        {
            /* The logic that needs for ParamA of SpecificProductA is now  
 pushed into the Visitor. */
            var productAVisitor = new SpecificProductAVisitor();
            ICommonInterface commonInterfaceWithParamA = product.GetCommonInterface(productAVisitor); 
        }
    }

    public class ConcreteConsumerB : IConsumer
    {
        public void Consume(Product product)
        {
        /* The logic that needs for ParamB of SpecificProductB is now  
 pushed into the Visitor. */
            var productBVisitor = new SpecificProductBVisitor();
            ICommonInterface commonInterfaceWithParamB = product.GetCommonInterface(productBVisitor); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If `ConcreteConsumerA` *requires* a `SpecificConfigurationA` to do its work, and not any `Configuration` instance then *it should accept `SpecificConfigurationA`*, and not `Configuration`.  Accepting any type of configuration and then just erroring at runtime when the caller doesn't know that you have requirements you haven't provided is just asking for bugs.

For your second solution you make a configuration object that simply has all of the information any consumer would ever need, so that no consumer can be given a configuration object that lacks what they need.  If that's entirely feasible for you, then that's great.  There's no way for any consumer to ever have an invalid object; it will always work just fine.

If you *can't* unify the objects, and there need to be different types of specific implementations, where different consumers can only handle certain types of configurations, then the final solution is the only real option.  It of course ensures that you can't ever provide a configuration value of an improper type.  While it may be more  *code* than just not having the types keep track of this information, that doesn't mean it's more *work*.  If the types weren't keeping track *for* you as to which of these consumers require which types of configurations then *you'd have to be keeping track of it somehow*, and if you got it wrong, instead of figuring it out immediately, due to your program not compiling, you wouldn't find out until that improper situation actually came up in testing and you got an invalid cast exception.  This is all the more problematic if the situation is uncommon, rather than a bug that happens in all situations, resulting in you missing it in your testing and it only being found by customers later.

Comment: Maybe this is **the** issue here: the objects can't be unified and I tried make them virtually fit but it just blew up in my face. Maybe the design has to be changed...

Comment: @Kzrystof Well you said they could be unified in your question, given that you listed it as a solution and other than indicating that you didn't like it, you said nothing about it not working.

Comment: You are correct :) I was not clear enough in my question. All the solutions I provided worked but left me with an unsatisfying impression. If the design is the issue (i.e. bad use of inheritance or abstractions for example) then I have no problem to consider changing it.

Answer (score 2):

If generic spreading is something you want to avoid, you can mitigate the runtime errors of option 1 giving the consumer a way to know if he's passing along the right types:

```
public interface IConsumer
{ 
    bool TryConsume(Product product);
}

public class ConcreteConsumerA : IConsumer
{
    public bool TryConsume(Product product)
    {
        if (product is SpecificProductA a)
        { 
            //consume a
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice variant of Solution 1 :)

Comment: But what is a caller going to be able to do with this?  It's not thrown an exception, but it still *didn't work*. And if the functionality was required, and not something optional, the caller will probably just need to throw an exception, odds are there isn't anything else they *can* do.  The result of this solution is that you've gotten an incorrect result at runtime (whether that incorrect result is an exception or simply the incorrect behavior) when you *could* have known about that bug in your code at compile time by not turning off the type system. At best this is just moving the problem.

Comment: @Servy Exactly. A variant of solution 1.

Comment: @servy yes I agree, but in some scenarios you simply don't know the runtime type, thats the whole point, this simply makes the usage nicer. Generics is all good, but if you have an `IConsumer<Product>` in hand, how does that help? You're still in the same bind. If you *know* you have a `IConsumer<ProductA>` in hand, how is that any different from knowing you have a `ConcreteConsumerA` in hand, which makes the whole issue moot?

Comment: @InBetween But this isn't such a situation.  The OP has made that clear by saying that the statically typed solutions work just fine, they just think that it's too much typing.  If a statically typed solution wasn't *possible* (because the relevant information isn't known at compile time) then you have no choice in the matter, and the question is pointless; only one option ever works.  The the other options *are specifically stated as being options*, so we know that this isn't a good idea.

Comment: @servy ok, but then why the need of an interface at all? If all types are statically known, why are we even dealing with an `IConsumer` interface to begin with? Something doesn't add up.

Comment: @InBetween There is an interface because the rest of the system uses IConsumer and Product. It does not need the details of what kind of Consumer or Product it is dealing with. It is able to work with the abstract concepts.